# How to add hooks to this React component?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, frontend, mantine

I have a `MultiStepForm` component that takes in a bunch of steps, allowing the user to navigate between multiple steps of a form. This is the code that I have:

```
export const MultiStepForm = <T>({ formSteps }: MultiStepFormProps<T>) => {
  const form = useForm<T>(formConfiguration);

  const shouldDisplayStep = (step: FormStep<T>) => {
    return !step.shouldDisplay || step.shouldDisplay?.(form.values);
  };

  const findNextValidStepIndex = (
    startIndex: number,
    isForward: boolean = true
  ) => {
    const stepIncrement = isForward ? 1 : -1;
    let i = startIndex;

    while (i >= 0 && i < formSteps.length) {
      if (shouldDisplayStep(formSteps[i])) {
        return i;
      }
      i += stepIncrement;
    }
    return -1;
  };

  const areStepFieldsValid = (step: FormStep<T>) => {
    let isValid = true;
    step.fields.forEach((f) => {
      if (form.validateField(f).hasError) {
        isValid = false;
      }
    });
    return isValid;
  };


  const goToNextStep = () => {
    if (!areStepFieldsValid(currentStep)) {
      return;
    }
    const nextStepIndex = findNextValidStepIndex(stepIndex + 1);
    if (nextStepIndex !== -1) {
      setStepIndex(nextStepIndex);
      triggerForwardTransition();
    }
  };

  const [stepIndex, setStepIndex] = useState(() => findNextValidStepIndex(0));
  const currentStep = formSteps[stepIndex];

  return (
    <Container>
      {currentStep.render(goToNextStep, form)}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

This is how I've specified my steps:

```
const clientDebtsSteps = [
  {
    fields: ['debtType'],
    render: (goToNextStep, form) => (
      <Stack spacing="xl">
        <Typography fz="lg" fw="medium">
          What kind of debt would you like to add?
        </Typography>
        <OptionsMenu
          data={[
            { value: 'carPayment', label: 'Car Payment' },
            { value: 'studentLoan', label: 'Student loan' },
            { value: 'creditCardPayment', label: ' Credit card payment' },
            { value: 'other', label: 'Other' },
          ]}
          {...form.getInputProps('debtType')}
        />
        {form.values.debtType && (
          <ArrowButton variant="outline" onClick={goToNextStep}>
            Looks Good
          </ArrowButton>
        )}
      </Stack>
    ),
  },
  {
    fields: ['debtInfo'],
    render: (goToNextStep, form) => (
      <Stack spacing="xl">
        <Typography fz="lg" fw="medium">
          Nice, so what is this debt about?
        </Typography>
        <TextInput label="Debt label" {...form.getInputProps('debtInfo')} />
        <ArrowButton variant="outline" onClick={goToNextStep}>
          Looks Good
        </ArrowButton>
      </Stack>
    ),
  },
  {
    fields: ['monthlyLoanAmount'],
    branchId: 'Loan Payments',
    render: (goToNextStep, form) => (
      <Stack spacing="xl">
        <Typography fz="lg" fw="medium">
          How much do you pay for your loan per month?
        </Typography>
        <NumberInput
          key="monthlyLoanAmount"
          icon={<TextIcon text="$" />}
          label="Monthly Payment"
          formatter={currencyFormatter}
          parser={currencyParser}
          {...form.getInputProps('monthlyLoanAmount')}
        />
        <ArrowButton variant="outline" onClick={goToNextStep}>
          Looks Good
        </ArrowButton>
      </Stack>
    ),
  },
  {
    fields: [],
    render: (goToNextStep, form, resetForm) => (
      <Stack spacing="xl">
        <Typography fz="lg" fw="medium">
          Nice! you’ve added a debt successfully, Proceed to add more info if
          there is any.
        </Typography>
        <SimpleTable
          rows={[
            {
              label: 'Type',
              value: sentenceCase(form.values.debtType!),
            },
            {
              label: 'Monthly amount',
              value: form.values.monthlyLoanAmount!,
            },
          ]}
        />
        <ArrowButton variant="subtle" compact sx={{ alignSelf: 'start' }}>
          Add Another Debt
        </ArrowButton>
        <ArrowButton
          sx={{ alignSelf: 'start' }}
          px="xl"
          onClick={() => {
            Router.push('/client/projects/1/debts');
          }}
        >
          Continue
        </ArrowButton>
      </Stack>
    ),
  },
];
```

Now, I want to use hooks within these steps but I cannot because these steps are JSX Elements and React complains that components must be defined at the top-level and must begin with a capitalized name. Is there a good way to add hooks to these steps i.e. something like this:

```
{
    fields: ['debtInfo'],
    render: (goToNextStep, form) => (
      const myData = useQuery(); // Like so
      <Stack spacing="xl">
        <Typography fz="lg" fw="medium">
          Nice, so what is this debt about?
        </Typography>
        <TextInput label="Debt label" {...form.getInputProps('debtInfo')} />
        <ArrowButton variant="outline" onClick={goToNextStep}>
          Looks Good
        </ArrowButton>
      </Stack>
    ),
  },
```